# Typo3 - Custom email newsletters with direct_mail

Tags: typo3, html-email, newsletter

Im building a newsletter and the start is like this:

```
DEAR ###USER_gender### ###USER_first_name### ###USER_last_name###
```

which outpouts

```
DEAR ###USER_gender### JOHN DOE
```

and I was hoping it would replace the gender mark with "Miss" and "Sir", depending on the value. How could I do this?

Comment: Do you use fe_user records or tt_address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra fields have to be added to the field list (see [docu](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/direct_mail/3.0.1/view/3/4/)). But I'm not sure whether this automatically works with non-string fields. Maybe [using a hook](http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/newsletter/90796/) is your solution or using [another extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/directmail_personalization) which adds a new field to tt_address.

Comment: The problem is that the field gender just has a "m" or a "f". I need to translate that into "Sir", "Mrs." or any other word I might need.

Comment: I added links to a hook solution or another extension providing a custom field.

Comment: Ok... I guess thats one way, but isnt there anything easier? Im not really up to build a new extension just for this

Comment: Well the biggest part of this extension is already there in that forum post and the rest is done by the kickstarter. You just have to put them togehter. Or you use one of the existing extensions (there are more than the one I linked).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to nest marker:

`###GENDER_###USER_gender######`

and then warp you content in a new template object:

```
10 = TEMPLATE
10 {
  template < yourAlreadyProcessedContent
  marks {
    GENDER_m = TEXT
    GENDER_m.value = Sir
  }
}
```

It's a bit unusual, but sometimes it's very useful.

(Personally I use it to replace version numbers in tt_content records.)

**Edit:**

Example for Dbugger:

Download the [Introduction Package](http://typo3.org/download/) and install it. After that add to the `Welcome` page a new template record with the following steup:

```
temp.mainTemplate = TEMPLATE
temp.mainTemplate {
  template = TEXT
  template.value = (
    Foo
    ###CONTENT###
    ###CONTENT###
    Bar
  )
  subparts {
    CONTENT < styles.content.get
  }
}

page = PAGE
page {
  typeNum = 0
  10 = TEMPLATE
  10 {
    template < temp.mainTemplate
    marks {
        TEST = TEXT
        TEST.value = ok
    }
}
```

Now include `CSS Styled Contnet` and enable the following options:

`clear constants`, `clear setup`, `rootlevel`

The output should look like that:

```
Foo

Congratulations ...

Bar
```

If you add `###TEST###` to the the tt_content record on the welcome page it will be replaced with `ok`.

This should work with direct mail, too.

**Edit:**
I'm sorry, this only works which *normal extension* which are use in the rendering process.

Comment: So this means that the markers of directmail are processed before the ones from the main template???

Comment: Ive tried it and it doesnt work... as suspected, the markers on the template object are evaluated first

Comment: Exactly. And as I said before: it is very useful if you use a lot of version numbers (for example on a download page - so you do not have to change all the content elements if a new version was released).

Comment: It works - I use it in my production environment.Hold on and I'll give you an example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12489/discussion-between-ivaldi-and-dbugger)

Comment: In the end this solution was invalid :(

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late, but here's the best solution for the salutation in `direct_mail` & `tt_address` .. works perfect for me.  The personalized marker is just `###USER_salutation###,`

https://blog.webentwickler.at/individuelle-marker-in-direct-mail/

Comment: Wow, 6 years later! I dont even use TYPO3 anymore :D But thanks anyway for your answer, mate.